# Trying to find & get a fixed DNS?

Tags: dns, dhcp

I'm trying to find our DNS details to specify in our printer so it can send scan docs to email.

Running a `cmd` prompt is showing details starting with `fe80::c6ea:` instead of a proper DNS address. Any ideas on how to get a correct DNS address that doesn't keep changing so we can specify a fixed DNS in the printer?

Comment: Hint to understand fe80::c6ea :  See IPv6 lionk local

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to understand your question but it looks like you want to tell your printer what DNS server to use to look up domain names.  And it appears that you think that you can read off this info from a local computer via the command prompt.  What does `ipconfig /all` show?  It's highly unlikely to display only the IPv6 address that you reported.

More fundamentally, if you are in an environment where machines get their settings from DHCP, then you shouldn't really even need to do this.  Set the printer up to use DHCP and make sure your DHCP server sends out DNS server info with each allocation.